# Where - Select by list of values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

There are two models
Categories:

```
public class Categories
{
    public int CategoriesId { get; set; }
    public int? StoroniyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Parent_id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Products> Produkt { get; set; }
}
```

model Produkt

```
public class Products
    {
        public int ProductsId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int CategoriesId { get; set; }
        public virtual Categories Categoria { get; set; }
        public int Possition { get; set; }
        public bool Glass { get; set; }
        public decimal price_opt { get; set; }
        public decimal price_rrc { get; set; }        
    }
```

In any way it is impossible to select the goods according to the parent category:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var CatId = await _context.Categories.Where(c => c.Parent_id == 3).ToListAsync();
    var applicationDbContext = _context.Products.Where(c => CatId.Equals(c.CategoriesId));
    return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

How to correctly write an operator Where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your corresponding line to the below line

```
var applicationDbContext = _context.Products.Where(c => CatId.Any(cat => cat.CategoriesId == c.CategoriesId));
```

You obtain a list of categories in your first `where` clause so you have to check if the Product belongs to all such categories.

I would do it a bit differently though

```
var products = from c in _context.Categories
               from p in _context.Products
               where c.CategoriesId == p.CategoriesId && c.Parent_id == 3
               select p;

return View(await products.ToListAsync());
```